# golangのWebアプリケーションのビルドについて

Tags: go

golangでは以下のようにファイルをビルドし、実行をすることができます。

```
go build hello.go
./hello
```

しかしながら、Webアプリケーションのような場合は、他に付属するファイルがたくさんあります。
そうした場合は、どのようにビルドするのでしょうか。

`main.go`がエントリポイントである場合は、

```
go build main.go
```

を実行し、

```
./main
```

を実行すれば、Webアプリケーションは起動するのでしょうか(私の環境では動きませんでした)。￥

初歩的な質問で申し訳ございませんが、回答をお願いします。

Comment: どの様なファイルがあるのかを示してください。ファイル名だけでも。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
エントリポイントのあるディレクトリで、

```
go build -o main
```

の後に、

```
./main
```

をすれば、Webアプリケーションを普通に起動できました。